# Where to enable permission for Google Map API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have done this before but I think they moved things around in `console.developers.google.com` so I forgot where to do it.

Basically, besides creating an API key and allowing the reference url, there is one more step we need to do that is not documented in `developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial` in order to allow the API to work. I remember it is a place you check things like `static map`, `canvas` etc.

Comment: In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth > APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under `APIs & auth > APIs`.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should have to enable the Google Maps Android Api from the google console under you project > API > Google Map Api > Enable